# mock methods regardless of params with Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I write an interface like this:

```
public interface IPlayer{

    boolean capture();

    boolean capture(String path);

}
```

I want both of the methods return true in my unit testing.For the first method, I mock like this:

```
IPlayer iplayer = Mockito.mock(IPlayer.class);
when(iplayer.capture()).thenReturn(true);
when(iplayer.capture("")).thenReturn(true);
```

This works well with the first method.But for the second method, it returns false. How can I get true regardless of the param **path** when I call iplayer.capture(path)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`anyString()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyString()) argument matcher:

```
when(iplayer.capture(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(true);
```